# Fancybox function nested into another function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm working on converting my gallery thumbnails into fancybox links but when I'm trying to target the image content under the `.gallery-overlay`, it doesn't work and the page just redirects to the photo's source. What am I doing wrong here? JQuery and fancybox linked properly,

```
$('.gallery-overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

brings out the fancybox after 2 (!) clicks, but in a useless, incorrect way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery-overlay').click(function() {
    $(this).children('img').fancybox();
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
.gallery-overlay img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-overlay:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)70%);
  transition: 1s;
}
.gallery-caption {
  color: white;
  top: 75%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 102;
  transition: 1s;
}
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-caption {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-overlay">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="photos/office_woman_l.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="photos/thumbnail.jpeg" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-overlay">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="photos/laptop_l.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="photos/thumbnail.jpeg" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-overlay">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="photos/glasses_woman_l.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="photos/thumbnail.jpeg" alt="thumbnail">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are already setting a *class* `fancybox` to the anchors you only need to bind that class to fancybox like `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` and drop the `.click()` method completely

Answer (score 2):

Fancybox works when clicking the a element which has a class fancybox not the image, so your script must be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery-overlay a').fancybox();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/ds5j8vz5/

Comment: It works also with this solution, but the way it makes the fancybox appear in the exact same way as at the solution below, check it out at http://laszlovaszi.com/yoursite/ in the 2nd row of the gallery.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply the `.fancybox()` to tag `<a>` and prevent the click event on this tag. Also, you should put the tag `<h3>` for inside the `.gallery-overlay`. When the caption appears, it covers the `.gallery-overlay` and the click event isn't triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery-overlay').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('a').fancybox();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/u9d2pwo8/

Comment: Just checked your solution, it sounds logic, but look at the way it makes the fancybox appear: http://laszlovaszi.com/yoursite/ - check the tumbnails, the 2nd row in the gallery.

Comment: You should put the ```<h3>``` to inside of ```.gallery-overlay```. It is **over the element** of click event. Also, you can add a loading icon to fancybox container.

Comment: I actually put at one of them and it made no difference, but now I've done it for your sake at all of them and still nothing :-/ It doesn't even open up at the first click, and when it does it's not adjusted at all.. What can we miss from here? http://laszlovaszi.com/yoursite/ You can check it, I've done as you asked.

Comment: Your HTML seems different.  Try to add ```class="fancybox" rel="portfolio"``` to ```<a>``` as the same way of your question.

Comment: The upper row is all right like that, those are links and I don't wanna display any image from them, but the downer row is made the way you say and it doesn't work :-/ `<div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="photos/office_woman_l.jpg"><img class="img-responsive" src="photos/thumbnail.jpeg" alt="thumbnail"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>`